# How to use a Bayesian Network to compute conditional probability queries

Tags: artificial-intelligence, bayesian

I am studying about Bayesian Network of my AI courses.
Does anyone know how to calculate causal inference and diagnostic inference in the attached picture?

Bayesian Network Example

[image]

Comment: Borderline off-topic. Related questions should better be asked in [the dedicated stack exchange site for stats and AI](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It would've been interesting to see the answer expressed as a Bayesian network using something like bnlearn

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to perform inference from a Bayesian network, the most naive of which is just [enumeration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5DHnmHtVmc).

Enumeration works for both causal inference and diagnostic inference.  The difference is finding out how likely the effect is based on evidence of the cause (causal inference) vs finding out how likely the cause is based on evidence of the effect (diagnostic inference).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Nick Larsen is a good one. I'll elaborate to give a worked solution to your problem since you might be looking for something a little more specific.

---

**Problem 1:** P(C|E). What is the probability of having a promising career (C=1) GIVEN the economic environment is positive (E=1)?

We use the factored structure of the Bayes net to write the full joint probability in terms of the factored variables.

[image]

Notice that you have just used the law of total probability to introduce the latent variables (S and J) and then marginalise (sum) them out. I have used the 'hat' to refer to not (~ in your question above). Notice too that once you have applied the rule of total probability, the Bayes net does a lot of the hard work for you by allowing you to factor the joint probability into a number of smaller conditional probabilities.

---

**Problem 2:** P(E|C). What is the probability that the economic environment is positive (E=1) GIVEN we observe that you have a promising career (C=1)?

[image]

Here we actually need to apply Bayes rule in the first line. Notice that you have an annoying normalising constant P(C) that is carried throughout. This term can be solved in much the same way as you solved Problem 1:

[image]

The computation of P(C=1|E=1) is solved in problem 1. I have left out the computation for P(C=0|E=1) = 0.5425 out but it is the same process as Problem 1.

Now you are in a position to solve for P(E|C) = .38/.65125 = .583